# The importance of c enumeration (typedef enum)

Tags: c

I recently saw this in an answer that was posted for me:

```
typedef enum
{
    NO_OP,
    ADDITION,
} operator_t;

int main()
{
    operator_t operator = NO_OP;
}
```

What is `typedef enum` and why should we use it?  I googled and found the following:
http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-enumeration

Right now it sounds slightly too technical for me so I don't think I understand what is going on or why anyone would use that.

Bonus (optional): What type of variable is the `operator_t`?

Comment: `typedef` and `enum` are seperate concepts. They can be used independantly of each other. So are you not understanding just `typedef`, just `enum`, both or the use of `typedef` with `enum`?

Comment: Isn't the example with the weekdays self explanatory ? The trick is to define your own variable.

Comment: [When to use enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571019/when-to-use-enums)

Comment: You may find [`static const` vs `#define` vs `enum` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-vs-enum-in-c/1674459#1674459) useful.  It isn't a direct answer to your main question, but it has some useful sidelights on why it is beneficial to use `enum` types in your code.

Comment: You should avoid identifiers ending in `_t`. That suffix is reserved by the standard and your code might fail to compile in future versions of the standard.

Answer (score 85):

1. It's definitely not "too technical".
2. "[typedef](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/typedef.html)" and "[enum](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/enum.html)" are two completely different things.
3. The basic reason to have "enums" is to avoid "magic numbers":

   Let's say you have three "states": STOP, CAUTION and GO.  How do you represent them in your program?

   One way is to use the string literals "STOP", "CAUTION" and "GO".  But that has a lot of problems - including the fact that you can't use them in a C "switch/case" block.

   Another way is to Map" them to the integer values "0", "1" and "2".  This has a lot of benefits.  But seeing "STOP" in your code is a lot more meaningful than seeing a "0".  Using "0" in your code like that is an example of a "[magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)".  Magic numbers are Bad: you want to use a "meaningful name" instead.

Before enums were introduced in the language, C programmers used macros:

```
   #define STOP 0
   #define CAUTION 1
   #define GO 2
```

A better, cleaner approach in modern C/C++ is to use an enum instead:

```
enum traffic_light_states {
  STOP,
  CAUTION,
  GO
};
```

Using a "typedef" just simplifies declaring a variable of this type:

```
typedef enum {
  STOP,
  CAUTION,
  GO
} traffic_light_states_t ;
```

Comment: Wow perfect explanation. How come there are hardly any sites that keep things so nice and compact for c starters?

Comment: May I ask now how does c associate traffic_light_states_t with the enum? I mean it is outside the enum brackets

Comment: "traffic_light_states_t" is simply an *ALIAS*.  The two declarations I gave above accomplish exactly the same thing.  The only difference is you'd declare a variable for first one `enum traffic_light_states my_traffic_light;`; vs. `traffic_light_states_t my_traffic_light;` for the typedef'd definition.  Look here for more details about "typedef": http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/typedef.html

Answer (score 39):

`typedef` is used to define an alternative name for an existing type. The `enum` could have declared like this:

```
enum operator_t
{
    NO_OP,
    ADDITION,
};
```

and then you could declare a variable of this type like so:

```
enum operator_t x = NO_OP;
```

This is kind of verbose so you would use `typedef` to define a shorter alias for this type:

```
typedef enum operator_t operator_t;
```

This defines `operator_t` to mean the type `enum operator_t` allowing you to initialize a variable like so:

```
operator_t x = NO_OP;
```

This syntax:

```
typedef enum
{
    NO_OP,
    ADDITION,
}   operator_t;
```

does the whole process in one step, so it defines an (untagged or tagless) `enum` type and gives it the alias `operator_t`.

Bonus: `operator_t` is an `enum` data type; read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type

Answer (score 9):

> What is typedef enum and why should we use it?

There are two different things going on there: a typedef and an enumerated type (an "enum").  A typedef is a mechanism for declaring an alternative name for a type.  An enumerated type is an integer type with an associated set of symbolic constants representing the valid values of that type.

Taking the enum first, the full form of an enum declaration consists of the `enum` keyword, followed by a tag by which that particular enum will be identified, followed by the symbolic enum constants in curly brackets.  By default, the enum constants correspond to consecutive integer values, starting at zero.  For example:

```
enum operator {
    NO_OP,
    ADDITION
};
```

As you can see, it has some similarities to a `struct` declaration, and like a `struct` declaration, variables of that enumerated type can be declared in the same statement:

```
enum operator {
    NO_OP,
    ADDITION
} op1, op2, op3;
```

or they can be declared later, by referencing the enum's tag:

```
enum operator op4, op5;
```

Also like a `struct` declaration, the tag can be omitted, in which case the enumerated type cannot be referenced elsewhere in the source code (but any declared variables of that type are still fine):

```
enum {
    NO_OP,
    ADDITION
} op1, op2, op3;
```

Now we get to the typedef.  As I already wrote, a typedef is a means to declare an alternative name for a type.  It works by putting the `typedef` keyword in front of something that would otherwise be a variable declaration; the symbol that would have been the variable name is then the alternative name for the type.  For instance this ...

```
typedef unsigned long long int ull_t;
```

declares `ull_t` to be an alternative name for type `unsigned long long int`.  The two type names can thereafter be used interchangeably (within the scope of the typedef declaration).

In your case, you have

```
typedef enum
{
    NO_OP,
    ADDITION,
}   operator_t;
```

which declares `operator_t` as an alias for the tagless enumerated type given.  Declaring a typedef in this way makes the enum usable elsewhere, via the typedef name, even though the enum is tagless.  This is a fairly common mechanism for declaring a shorthand name for an enumerated type, and an analogous technique is common for structs, too.

> Bonus (optional): What type of variable is the operator_t?

As I explained, the `operator_t` is not a variable, it is a type.  In particular, it is an enumerated type, and the symbols `NO_OP` and `ADDITION` represent values of that type.

Answer (score 3):

Typedefs for enums, structs and unions are a complete waste. They hide important information for the questionable benefit of saving a few characters to type.

Don't use them in new code.

Technically, a typedef introduce an *alias*, i.e. a new name for something that already exists. This means, typedefs are *not* new types. The type system will treat them just like the aliased type.

The downvoters may please educate themselves by, for example, reading the wonderful Peter van der Linden book *Expert C Programming* where the case against typedefs for enum/struct/union is made.

Comment: The downvoter voted down because your rant does not answer the question.

Comment: @LarsFriedrich Fair enough. To quote the OP: "What is typedef and why should we use it?" is not answered clearly and with a vengeance?

Comment: Not going to down vote because I believe you did answer the question "What is typedef and why should we use it?" However I personally disagree with you. I think having struct or enum or union before type defined as such is redundant it doesn't add much to the program. It's very similar to Hungarian notation IMO. Now there may be cases like with hungarian notation where this is somewhat helpful, but I dont think it's right to say we should never use typedef. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: What is typedef was not answered before the edit , second the purpose of it is to hide information, stating that it hides information is bad, is no reasoning. Functions hide information, too. I call the function and don't need to bother about the details of the function. structs themselves and enumerations hide information. Using an enumeration means I don't know the value without looking it up. There is "less visible" is just not a sufficient answer. The same kind of "argument" is used to explain why "goto" is bad.

Comment: Although I'm not sure I agree that typedefs for enums, structs, and unions are a *complete* waste, any more than typedefs for other types are a waste, I agree that they indeed do hide information in a manner that can negatively effect development and maintenance.  Specifically, they hide the answers to important questions such as "if variable `t1` is a `thing_t` and variable `t2` is a `struct thing` then can I assign `t1`'s value to `t2`?"

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has a good discussion of what a typedef is

> typedef is a keyword in the C and C++ programming languages. The purpose of typedef is to form complex types from more-basic machine types[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) and assign simpler names to such combinations. They are most often used when a standard definition or declaration is cumbersome, potentially confusing, or likely to vary from one implementation to another.
> [See this page for a detailed discussion of Typedef in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef)

Enumerated Types allow us to create our own symbolic names for a list of related ideas.

Given the example you gave I'm guessing you can use enum to select which arithmetic operation to use for a particular set of variables.

The following example code should give you a good idea on what enum is useful for.

```
enum ARITHMETIC_OPERATION {ADD, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY};

int do_arithmetic_operation(int a, int b, enum ARITHMETIC_OPERATION operation){

   if(operation == ADD)
       return a+b;

   if(operation == SUBTRACT)
       return a-b;

   if(operation == MULTIPLY)
       return a*b;
}
```

If you didn't have enum, you would do something like this instead:

```
#define ADD 0
#define SUBTRACT 1
#define MULTIPLY 2

int do_artithmetic_operation(int a, int b, int operation);
```

This alternative is less readable, because operation is not really an integer but a symbolic type that represents an arithmetic operation that is either ADD, MULTIPLY, or SUBTRACT.

The following links provide good discussions and sample code that uses Enum.

[http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/C_Language/enumerated_types.html](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Egermain/PPS/Topics/C_Language/enumerated_types.html)

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/enum.html

http://cplus.about.com/od/introductiontoprogramming/p/enumeration.htm

Comment: What I dont get is, how can any of the if statements evaluate to true if the types ADD, SUBSTRACT, MULTIPLY have no meaning? For me it looks like operation == NAN

Comment: Ok based on the other answers I assume ADD is 0, Substract 1, Multiply 2. So basically you are saying: Operation == 0?

Comment: @Asperger it's a user defined symbolic name. it's just so you can use the function like this  `do_arithmetic_operation(1, 2, ADD);` `do_arithmetic_operation(1, 2, SUBTRACT);` `do_arithmetic_operation(1, 2, MULTIPLY);`

Comment: @Asperger, yes that's how it works under the hood but you don't have to think of it like that. If you didn't use enum you would have something like, `#define ADD = 0`, `int operation`, `if (operation == ADD) return a + b`

Answer (score 1):

typedef and enum are two different concepts. You can rewrite the code like this:

```
enum operator
{
  NO_OP,
  ADDITION
};

typedef enum operator operator_t;
```

The first statement declares an enumeration called `operator`, with two values. The second statement declares that the enumeration `operator` is now **also** to be known as the type `operator_t`.

The syntax does allow to combine these two statements into one statement:

```
 typedef enum operator
 {
    NO_OP,
    ADDITION,
 } operator_t;
```

And finally to omit a name for the enumeration, as there is a datatype for it anyway:

```
 typedef enum
 {
    NO_OP,
    ADDITION,
 } operator_t;
```